# How to solve magento 2 localhost not working properly

Tags: magento2, php-7, ubuntu

[image]

I already run comment

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/www/html/myproject/*
```

but still not showing 
how i can fix this??

Comment: try this commands **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile &&php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f** and let me know it works or not

Comment: can i run both cmds at same time

Comment: yes just run all bold font text I have combined all command into one

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if not working.

Comment: wait i am runing cmds..

Comment: HI. Have you tried with running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f command? If still not working then remove /generated/code/* and /generated/metadata/* folder.

Comment: why deploying comment takes too long to run

Comment: Yes it take some time because it checks frontend and adminhtml static files.

Comment: Not working with deploy comment

Comment: how to use  "remove /generated/code/* "  - not comment

Answer (score 0):

Follow this below steps :

```
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then, execute this command in your terminal : `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Find below text :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And change it by below text :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then, execute this command : `sudo service apache2 restart`